# Faithful action

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

I need to prove that $(\mathbb{Z}_{2^n},+)$ has no faithful action on a set of size less than $2^n$. I tried to use division criterion since if an action is faithful (that is the kernel of the associate homomorphism is $0$) you have a injection of the initial group in $ S_{|X|}$, therefore you can use Lagrange theorem), but it did not work. I am relatively stuck so I will be thankful if a person can help me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks for the improvements you've made, Anonyme.

Comment: @Anonyme (since you're new and haven't accepted anything yet) If you find an answer useful/satisfactory, please accept it (by clicking the check below the vote count). This gives the question answerer (me) some credit, and helps others see that the question has been satisfactorily answered when searching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $k < 2^n$, and say $\rho: \mathbb{Z}_{2^n} \to S_k$ is injective. Then, $\rho(1)$ has order $2^n$. Each cycle in the disjoint cycle decomposition of $\rho(1)$ must have order dividing $2^n$ (the order of $\rho(1)$) but not equal to $2^n$ (as $k < 2^n$). Then, the order of $\rho(1)$ must divide $2^{n-1}$, as each of the cycles in its disjoint cycle decomposition does. But this means $\text{ord}(\rho(1)) < 2^n$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: thanks for your help

Comment: $\rho(1)$ has order 1 no ?

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}_{2^n}$ is an additive group, so (1 being the generator) $1$ has order $2^n$, meaning (because $\rho$ is an injection) $\rho(1)$ has order $2^n$.

Comment: Ha okay thanks !